# How to sort a MYSQL table in a permanent way?

Tags: mysql

I am a having a table with column Symbol and Weight(only two Column) . 
I need to sort table according to weight of the symbols, that i can do by

```
SELECT symbol, weight FROM symbols ORDER BY weight DESC
```

but this wont change my table, but it will give me a sorted output(temporary).

I want to sort table permanently. How can i do that?

Comment: Tables in a relational database are not "sorted". You simply can't do that.

Comment: SELECT never changes neither the table data, nor the structure.

Comment: SELECT never changes neither the table data, nor the structure,
I know that man, that is my problem....

Comment: I had to drop the primary key, sort the table, and then add the key back. `ALTER TABLE tableName DROP COLUMN PrimaryKeyName; ALTER TABLE tableName ORDER BY SortColumn1, sortColumn2, etc...; ALTER TABLE tableName ADD COLUMN primaryKeyName INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, ADD PRIMARY KEY (primaryKeyName);`

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You can do this with ALTER TABLE

f.e.

```
ALTER TABLE tablename ORDER BY columnname ASC;.
```

but be aware that the table does not remain in this order after inserts and deletes

Comment: @MohdSuleman Make sure to mark the answer correct when you can.

Comment: My Problem is solved, Alter table changed the order in the table itself. Now i can select already sorted records in the table. Only by writing `SELECT symbol, weight FROM symbols ORDER` instead of `SELECT symbol, weight FROM symbols ORDER BY weight DESC`

Comment: I marked this down because obviously (and admittedly as the respondent has suggested), it's meaningless. It should not be accepted as a correct answer.

Comment: Strawberry is right, if my solution has solved your problem maybe you should edit your question.

Comment: @jannic Answer solves my problem, becoz i have a static table. I dont perfom any insert or any delete in the table. My table is created in the starting of the script and it is deleted in the as soon the scripts end... and you can tell me what more should i add in the question. Alter Table is changing the table permanently, that i what i had asked.

Comment: @Strawberry thats a point about how you understand this question. Even if this is an old one, I just had the same question with the same background. Permanent pointed to "for now" without an eye on inserts. I've searched for this on google in the same wording and finally got my solution here.

Comment: @C4ud3x not much has changed in 2.5 years. Rows in an RDBMS table represent unordered sets. It's still meaningless to 'order' them on insert. This answer remains misleading and the community as a whole would be best served by its deletion.

Comment: @Strawberry Rows do represent unordered sets but they also have a physical storage order that in some cases can greatly affect the performance of certain queries. I'm not saying that necessarily pertains to how this question was asked. I'm also not saying that data will remain in that order or that that order should ever be relied upon. See MySQL and MS SQL Server "Clustered Indexes", Oracle "Index Organized Tables" (IOT), or PostgreSQL "CLUSTER"ed tables.

Comment: @NightOwl So what *are* you saying?

Comment: @Strawberry I guess I'm saying what I'm not saying which is a bit of a conundrum. The gist of my comment was that the ordering the OP wanted can be achieved however imperfect it might be. The main reason I took the time to comment at all was that I misread your post and thought you said the question should be deleted rather than the answer. I'll go back to not saying what I'm saying and not reading what I'm misreading but but I'll keep it all to myself now ;-)

Comment: It works good, but only in table without indexes or foreign keys, and that's not very usual.

Comment: What this "works" on is the physical order. You can hope that that affects query planning and performance; there is no guarantee.  @CyberBoy wants "give me a sorted output" "permanently". Nothing but ORDER BY will definitely "give me a sorted output", ever.

Comment: There are risks associated with that statement, https://dev.mysql.com/worklog/task/?id=3681

Comment: @JannicBeck how to do with Length(), ALTER TABLE tablename ORDER BY LENGTH(columnname) ASC;.

Answer (score 2):

Actually you can add a new integer column `sort` and set it as **primary key**. If you already has primary key, just change that to **unique** would be OK.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out how to make a sorted table! First, you have to make sure that you don’t need a primary key in that ordered table, which is very probably the case! What you do is you do your sekect statement into a temporary table then you select the first row in the temporary table and insert it in the ordered tablethen you delete that row from the temporary table. Make sure you have a primary key in the temporary table so you can delete the row easily. And then you do that until The temporary table is empty. Let me know if that works for you.