# How can I order alphabetically a table after each time I insert a new raw?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying with :

```
"CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `alphabetic sorting by surname` AFTER INSERT ON `contacts` FOR EACH ROW ALTER TABLE contatti ORDER BY surname ASC"
```

But I get
    #1422 - Explicit or implicit commit is not allowed in stored function or trigger.

It's long time I don't touch databases, what do I need to do?

It's supposed to be a phone numbers list that will be opened on multiple smartphones by an app, so it doesn't make sense to sort the contact list each time on phones, to me it looks more efficient to keep it sorted on server side.

Thanks anyone.

Comment: the premise of the question is false. Rows in an RDBMS database have no order - other than that established by an ORDER BY clause in a query.

Comment: I think OP is looking at the [MyISAM row ordering](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html#alter-table-row-order), but given that there are no guarantees that MySQL will be able to use the ordering, and that most queries will re-specify an ORDER BY, it's more likely to slow things down than help.  The server should be caching your ordered fetch anyway.  See also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19824928/how-to-sort-a-mysql-table-in-a-permanent-way/19824962#19824962) (and @Strawberry 's comments on it).

Comment: Will all those users really open the *same* list of contacts? Same records, same columns, the complete table?

Comment: @Strawberry i'm working on phpmyadmin. if I run "ALTER TABLE contatti ORDER BY surname ASC", I actually get what I want when I run "SELECT * FROM `contatti`", without specifying any ORDER BY clause. is that clause run in any implied way?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner yes, they do

Comment: @AC thanks, I'll check this out

Comment: @MarcoGioia No. Not in any meaningful sense. If you add an index or rebuild the table in some way this fragile 'order' could easily be corrupted. You must not rely on it.

Answer (score 0):

Tables are not ordered by definition and a query would have to have an `ORDER BY` clause to guarantee a specific order of the result rows.

You can, however, create a **covering index**. It starts with limiting columns, i.e. columns used in the `WHERE` clause, followed by the columns in `ORDER BY`, followed by all other columns selected. The DBMS will then be able to select all data from the index without accessing the actual table and the data will come in the desired order.

The query will still contain the appropriate `ORDER BY` clause of course, but the DBMS will (hopefully) notice that it doesn't have to perform a sort operation anymore to get the data in the desired order.

**Example 1:**

```
create index idx_contacts_byarea on contacts (area, surname, firstname, phone);

select firstname, surname, phone from contacts where area = 51 order by surname;
```

**Example 2:**

```
create index idx_contacts_all on contacts (surname, firstname, phone);

select firstname, surname, phone from contacts where order by surname;
```