# Alphabetical auto-order in HTML SQL code

Tags: html, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I imported the 3 tables in a file to my database. Worked perfectly.

Here's the file code: https://pastebin.com/EVr9qGxe

```
....
```

However, I want to change the variable in each table so I went to phpMyAdmin to change the variables in the tables.
They change just fine, however, the options appear in alphabetical, and not the order I entered them in or the country_id

for example if I entered

USA with country_id 1

France with country_id 2

France appears first in the list.

So my question is, what should I change in the code linked above in order to remove the alphabetical auto-order and make the options appear by their ID?

Comment: `Order by country_id`  - pls read a tutorial first

Comment: When asking a question it is best to include only the relevant code in the question rather than a link to an external website... especially where that website may change

Comment: The rows in a table have no order.  The rows you `SELECT` have a predictable order only if you add `ORDER BY ...`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19824928/how-to-sort-a-mysql-table-in-a-permanent-way). There's no way of permanently changing this behavior I'm aware of. You could add

```
ALTER TABLE `your_table` ORDER BY `column_name`
```

But the table will 're-order' itself back to where it was on the next CRUD operation performed on that table, **and for some databases this query simply won't work**.

As you are using phpMyAdmin, there's a simpler solution without coding- just enter your database, choose your table, and click on any column. Clicking on any column will order your table by values from that column. Clicking it again will change ordering from ascending to descending.

Rows in relational database are not really ordered, but you can order them when needed, by performing queries (with use of **ORDER BY**). For example, if you need to select all rows from table 'users', and order them by 'creation_date', you'd simply use SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY creation_date, but it won't change rows ordering in the table itself- you'd just get ordered result displayed.

Comment: That query works for MyISAM, but not InnoDB.  Do not use it.