# How to reorganize the records in a postgres table and persist it permanently

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following table structure

```
id      name
--------------
10991   Shoug 
10990   Moneera 
10989   Abc
10988   xyz
```

`id` is the primary key column, As you can see the id is in decreasing order (ie: `select * from users` returns the records in this order) because of the way the data was inserted.

**How do I resort the table in the ascending order of the primary key permanently?** Preferably with SQL alone?

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19824962/2693543) but its not working for me. I am using Postgres as the database.

Comment: `select * from users order by id` - sets are unordered

Comment: Please post table definition, do you use step of sequence as -1? `select * from users` could return data in any order. Table itself is unordered, period.

Comment: Actually, The table sequence is +1 only. But the data is fetched from one old database, in which the primary keys are not exactly in any order, but since we need to keep the primary keys as the same, the guy working on it populated the  db as it is,

Comment: Table is unordered, I get it. But can I reorganize the records in the asc order of `id` column, so further `select *` returns the records properly?

Comment: Without explicit `ORDER BY` the order is not guaranteed

Comment: Got it, Thanks @LukaszSzozda

Answer (score 2):

> How do I resort the table in the ascending order of the primary key permanently?

You are missing a fundamental concept about relational databases.  In SQL, tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no "permanent" ordering.  The only ordering is provided by the `order by` clause on a query.

Some databases support a concept called "clustering"/"clustered indexes".  This means that the data on data pages is actually ordered according to some key.  In these databases, even when using a table with a clustered index, you are still not guaranteed that the data is returned in any particular order.  Unless you use `ORDER BY`.

Postgres does not support this functionality, so even this is not available.

Comment: Got it, Thanks :)

Comment: Simple scenario even with clustered index parallel execution plan could return  rows in different order than index

Answer (score 0):

Apparently not possible in Postgres.

Curious what your use case was for this.  I was researching any downside to using UUID as PK in Postgres, which led me to your post.  Since pg does not physically reorder the data according to PK, I concluded that only the size (vs traditional sequence) would be the difference.  I'm more used to SQL Server creating a Cluster index and reordering data by default.

As your link in your OP suggests, you can force it to reorder, but it is not persistent.  Postgres also has a CLUSTER command to do this.  This does lock your table, though.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-cluster.html

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/38710/how-does-postgresql-physically-order-new-records-on-disk-after-a-cluster-on-pri