# How can MySQL records be reordered by a certain column permanently?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'll use an example for this.

Say I'm taking RSS feeds, going through their items, and storing some information about each item in a DB. I'm using [SimplePie](https://github.com/simplepie/simplepie) for processing the feeds, and [Josh Campbell's MySQLi wrapper](https://github.com/ThingEngineer/PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class#insert-query) for the DB actions.

For each entry, I will save the item title, the time the item was published (retrieved from the feed), the time the item was added to my DB (defined at the time of inserting to DB), and an auto-incremented ID assigned to each.

```
function process_rss($rss_url) {
      require_once './feed-parser/vendor/autoload.php';
      $feed = new SimplePie();
      // some feed processing logic here
      $items = $feed->get_items();
      
      $data = array();
      foreach ($items as $item) {
            $data[] = array(
                  'name'      => $item->get_title(),
                  'published' => $item->get_date(),
                  'created'   => time()
            );
      }
      $insert = ... // db insert query with the $data array  
      if ($insert) {
            return 'Imported';
      } else {
            return 'Try again...';
      }
}
```

Now assume I ran this function 3 times with 3 different feeds, and a total of 7 items were processed and inserted to the DB. They are inserted at the order in which they were processed, so my table would appear as follows:

```
ID  | Name    |  Published    |  Created
----------------------------------------
1   | Track 1 |  1595147815   |  1594986945
2   | Track 2 |  1594996785   |  1594986945
3   | Track 3 |  1595146567   |  1594986945
4   | Track 4 |  1594996598   |  1594986945
5   | Track 5 |  1594996096   |  1594986945
6   | Track 6 |  1594986545   |  1594986945
7   | Track 7 |  1594986609   |  1594986945
```

What I want to do now, is to sort that table by the `published` column permanently (rather than sorting while fetching the entries from the DB).

Taking the above example, the desired output would look like this:

```
ID  | Name    |  Published    |  Created
----------------------------------------
6   | Track 6 |  1594986545   |  1594986945
7   | Track 7 |  1594986609   |  1594986945
5   | Track 5 |  1594996096   |  1594986945
4   | Track 4 |  1594996598   |  1594986945
2   | Track 2 |  1594996785   |  1594986945
3   | Track 3 |  1595146567   |  1594986945
1   | Track 1 |  1595147815   |  1594986945
```

Looking into the answers [provided here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19824928/how-to-sort-a-mysql-table-in-a-permanent-way), it is indicated that using `ALTER` and `ORDER BY` will not persist the changes upon new inserts. How would I go about achieving this?

Comment: _“How would I go about achieving this?”_ - ideally, you wouldn’t. Don’t mess with IDs. They have one job, and one job only - uniquely identify a record. As soon as you are assigning _any_ other meaning to them (and you must be doing that here somehow, otherwise you would not ask for this in the first place), you are _doing things wrong_.

Comment: Tnx for your input, I've edited to question to reflect only the persistent-sorting part, without the reassigning of IDs.

Comment: “Permanent sorting” makes rather little sense either. Database results _do not have_ any default order, unless you specify one when reading the data. (You might _get_ them in a particular order, even if you didn’t ask for it in your SELECT query - but that is based on how the database has written the records to disk, and is nothing you should _ever_ rely on. What you _think_ was a specific order at that point, could change when the database gets reorganized/optimized.) If you want results to be in a specific order, then specify that order while you are _reading_ the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can MySQL records be reordered by a certain column permanently?

You Can't Do That™.  Seriously. And you will be sorry if you try.

Seriously, rows in SQL databases *have no inherent order.*  If you do not specify `ORDER BY` on your query the server is free to return the set of rows you requested in any order it wants.  If you get them in a particular order that somehow matches your expectation, it is a lucky coincidence.

As tables grow, SQL databases sometimes start using different ways of accessing them. And, without any ORDER BY specification, those different ways of accessing them may generate different orderings.  So, if you need a particular order but you don't specify it, sometime in the life of your application the order will change. When you don't expect it to. And your users will suddenly be baffled by strange results.

Use `ORDER BY`.