# Update DB using order by

Tags: sql

I want to update my database so that everyone view table order by Type(TIPO).
But when I use the query:

```
UPDATE TABLE
ORDER BY TIPO ASC
```

shows me error: unexpected token: ORDER required: SET

This is the database view
[image]

Can someone help me how to update DB so everyone when looking at DB will see sorted by TIPO?

Comment: Please share more details, like the DB system you are using

Comment: For MySQL, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19824928/how-to-sort-a-mysql-table-in-a-permanent-way might help

Comment: Tables are not ordered. If you want to show ordered results use ORDER BY TIPO in a query.

Answer (score 0):

SQL tables represent *unordered* (multi)sets.  Period.  There is no ordering associated with the table.

If users want to see rows in a particular order, then the query they use to look at the table needs to include an `order by`.

Comment: Isn't possible to order a table then? We can only order in queries for a viewing?

Comment: @wsn . . . Let me repeat:  **tables are unordered**.  That should answer your question.  In addition, result sets are unordered as well, unless the outermost `select` has an `order by`.